# Is editing one text file several times at the same time dangerous?

Tags: bash, shell, race-condition

I read a text file with names in it. When some conditions are true, I remove the name (a whole line) from the list, with

`grep -v $var $list.txt > $list.tmp; mv $list.tmp $list.txt`

But I have multiple scripts doing the same thing on the same list, but at different positions. Can it be harmful if two scripts try to edit a line at the same time ? Do I have to add something ? Cheers

Comment: Yes. Use a database for this.

Comment: Yes, it appears that your code is prone to race conditions. Try to add a lock condition.

Comment: A better approach altogether is to collect a list of all the strings you want to remove, then change the file just once. This should be significantly more efficient as well; rewriting the same data many times is the main bottleneck here. Try `grep -v -e string1 -e string2` or `grep -vF patternfile` or refactor to a simple `sed` script.